# Flutter Database not Showing when first app launch

Tags: flutter, provider, sqflite

I'm making a simple todolist application using sqflite. but when the application is opened/flutter is run for the first time, the data on the main page does not appear. the data will appear when I add a new data. how to solve it?

Github repo link: https://github.com/Itqonibras/todoo_app.git

Pre-existing data will appear when the application is first opened

Comment: I didn't look very hard, but is there anything that triggers *loading* the database data when the program starts?  I didn't see anything for that.

Comment: Provide your codes to see what is the problem!